# Что будет если у человека, назначившего конкурс, будет меньше 51 репутации?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация, конкурс

Я несколько раз видел людей, которые назначали конкурс, но к его концу у них оставалось меньше 51 репутации. Я как-то не догадался посмотреть, что получится, ну вот и остался такой вопрос. Что случится?

Comment: Почитайте в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), там есть ответ на ваш вопроc, а также в ссылке на дубликат

Comment: Из дубликата: «Для того чтобы объявить конкурс, вы должны иметь минимум 75 баллов репутации; при этом ваша репутация также не должна быть меньше устанавливаемой награды». Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, 75-50 = 25, что меньше 51.

Comment: @Kromster, я имею в виду, что не вижу связи между этим комментарием и вопросом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ничего.

Из справки  -- "При объявлении награды соответствующая сумма баллов будет изъята из вашей репутации сразу после начала конкурса (а не по его завершению)."